# Phonegap music playing in background

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, background

Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is when someone presses home button the music from Youtube doesn't stop playing.

The purpose off my application is run Youtube in the background, I am trying to accomplish it with `Cordova`/`Phonegap`.

**EDIT:**     I searched really hard for answers but I cant find any.

**EDIT2:**    I downloaded a plugin [Background Mode](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/2056) but it only manages to play music when the screen is off, not when I am on Facebook and have the application in background.

Comment: You should add formatting to your answer, it will be easier to read and more people would be interested to provide an answer.

Comment: improved formatting and explanations